# Giving a dependent drop-down list option a value to create a function

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript, (first few days)...

Im creating an airline booking form and want to display a seat pitch price dependent on what class the passenger has selected.

Im not to sure how to retrieve a value from the dependent drop-down script so i can create an array to associate the selected value with a price. Heres my script...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function dropdownlist(listindex)
{
    document.flightform.pitch.options.length = 0;
    switch (listindex)
    {
        case "Economy":
            document.flightform.pitch.options[0]=new Option("28","28");
            document.flightform.pitch.options[1]=new Option("29","29");
            break;
        case "Biz":
            document.flightform.pitch.options[0]=new Option("30","");
            document.flightform.pitch.options[1]=new Option("32","");
            break;
        case "First":
            document.flightform.pitch.options[0]=new Option("40","");
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
var Seat_pitch= new Array ();

Seat_pitch["28"] = 400;
//etc.....
//etc.....

function getSeatpitch()
{
    var Seatpitch=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["flightform"];
    var selectedpitch = theForm.elements["pitch"];

    Seatpitch = Seat_pitch[selectedpitch.value];

    return Seatpitch;
}

function calcTotal()
{
    var Total = getSeatpitch()  ;

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Your flight Total is &pound;"+Total;
}

</script>

<htmL>
<body>
    <label>Class type</label><br />
    <select id="class"  name='class' onchange="javascript: dropdownlist(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">

        <option value="Economy">Economy</option>
        <option value="Biz">Business</option>
        <option value="First">First</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        document.write('<select name="pitch" id="pitch"></select>')
    </script>
    <div id="totalPrice"></div>

</html>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a form called "flightform" in your html, but you're referencing this in your javascript.

In fact your tags are a bit skew wiff, re-order them like so:

```
<html>
<script>
...
</script>
<body>
<form name="flightform">
...
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You should then be able to get the price by calling the getSeatpitch function.

Comment: sorry yes is do have a form called flightform ive just not copied it on

Comment: Have you managed to get this working - I got your example to work with the correct tags, and a call to the calcTotal function. Also Xavi López has provided a good answer above - you should be able to see where you're going wrong because he has a working fiddle based off your code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think to use jQuery framework? There is a lot of useful things, so that you don't need no develop your own bicycle. For example you code could be rewritten as:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Connect jQuery from Google library storage -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Create select for class, with id #class -->
        <select id="class" name="class">
            <option value="0">Econom</option>
            <option value="1">Business</option>
            <option value="2">First</option>
        </select>
        <!-- Create select for place, with id #place -->
        <select id="place" name="place" disabled="disabled"></select>
        <!-- Create view place for price, with id #price -->
        <span id="price"></span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // available places to choose 
            var available = {
                0:      {
                    25: 50
                },
                1:      {
                    26: 100
                },
                2:      {
                    21: 200,
                },
            }

            // When the document is totally loaded, do that things that's defined in function(e) {}
            $(document).ready(function(e){
                // Bind trigger for class select changing, where $('select#class') - find element that in DOM select inputs and has id="class"
                // When it change, call function(e) {}, inside this function $(this) will be the select itself
                $('select#class').live('change', function(e){
                    // find place select input
                    var place = $('select#place');
                    // if it's disabled, unblock it, and clean all options inside
                    place.removeAttr('disabled').find('option').remove();
                    // foreach places in available create option and put it into place select
                    for (var i in available[$(this).val()]) {
                        place.append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
                    }
                    // behave like place select have changed, and trigger listener above
                    place.change();
                });

                $('select#place').live('change', function(e){
                    $('span#price').html(available[$('select#class').val()][$(this).val()]);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Totally working example.
Somehow like that... Strongly recommend you not to use raw JavaScript.

Comment: thankyou very much for that. like i say ive just starting learn javascript, amybe i should start learn jquery....

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing a call to `calcTotal` in your code.

You could just call it in the `onchange` event of the `<select name="pitch">`, like

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    document.write('<select name="pitch" id="pitch" onchange="calcTotal();"></select>')
</script>
```

See it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apTCp/2/).

I don't understand why is this `<select>` being written by means of `document.write`, though.

I'd recommend also calling `calcTotal()` in the `<select name="class">`'s `onchange` event listener, so that the total will update when changing the class (and therefore the pitch). Remember to also call `dropdownlist()` and `calcTotal()` at page load time (for instance, with `<body onload="calcTotal()">`), as you will have the first value preselected.

Or even better, provide blank values for both dropdowns, and check for them in `calcTotal` in order to clear the text that displays the total if there's no class selected.

Also, as to the original question of how to get the value from a `<select>`, you could just do access the element's `value` property instead of `options[selectedIndex].value]`.

**PD** I've updated the fiddle to provide blank options and clear the total display in case there are no proper options selected.